# Jekyll livereload browser not connecting

Tags: ruby, jekyll, livereload

I'm not a ruby expert here, and I'm new to jekyll just trying to get the livereload plugin to work on a blank theme.

plugin: https://github.com/RobertDeRose/jekyll-livereload

I setup jeckyll with a blank theme with `jekyll new theme --blank` When I run jekyll serve, I can see `LiveReload Server: http://127.0.0.1:35729` output in terminal so I guess it should be working, but the browser reloading doesn't work. However it does work if I use the default theme.

When using the default theme, there's an extra message: `LiveReload: Browser connected`when I run jekyll serve. That message doesn't appear with blank theme.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is old, but I was facing the same issue, so I thought I'd share the solution that worked for me.

You just need to add [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/03-front-matter/) to the top of your html file, that's two triple-dashed lines, so your html file should look like this:

```
---
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```